# UnBEARable trap monk

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, ranged-attack, traps, improvised-weaponry

While I was playing with different possible NPC bosses in Pathfinder, I came across the Monk and his humble "Throw Anything". So I am wondering, if a Monk has "Craft Trap" and makes a butt-load of bear traps before hand:

1. How far can he throw the trap?
2. Does he need to ready (not draw) the trap?
3. If he does need to ready, what kind of action is it?
4. How much damage does it do? (Does it strike for its size as an improvised weapon or its regular damage[2d6+3]? Does it then clamp on the target and deal activation damage?)
5. If the attack misses or doesn't go through the armour, does the trap remain untriggered or does it land used?

Comment: There is some prior discussion about thing topic over at the paizo forum: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l62p?Offensive-Bear-Traps

Comment: It's a great start, but it doesn't give me a sure answer (considering distance thrown and activation). Still, it answers my questions about damage, thanks for the tip!

Comment: normally, you do not edit the question as it is being resolved. It make the question less readable/useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trap would likely not activate as desired. (unfortunately I do not have a hard rule to cite for this)

The rules I do know and answers I can provide:

Throw Anything, simply allows you to make attacks with improvised ranged weapons with a bonus instead of the usual penalties.

Throwing a Bear trap is an improvised ranged weapon and by the rules it has a range of 10ft and does damage to a similiarly size/shaped weapon from the weapon table.

> To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an
>   improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to
>   the weapon list to find a reasonable match. An improvised weapon
>   scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a
>   critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10
>   feet.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons

If you want to build a character based around throwing things, have
 you considered the Brutal Bolas?

> Bola, Brutal
>
> Benefit: These bolas function as standard bolas, but they deal lethal
>   damage rather than nonlethal damage.
>
> Weapon Feature(s): trip (ranged)

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/brutal-bolas

Comment: Thanks for the input; it answered nearly everything I was looking for! Guess I'll look through the trap discussions about what state the trap is in/how long it takes to get it ready

Answer (score 0):

### Not by RAW

There's no rules for 'throwing' traps, or trying to land a trap's activation trigger on someone's face with a throw.

Under RAW it would likely be treated as just the damage from an improvised thrown weapon, but RAW breaks down in this circumstance because the actual process of setting a trap isn't elaborated on enough to define what would be happening in this sense.

### But you're the GM.

Houserules are the GM's purview.  In a situation like this without clearly defined RAW, it's not even a huge stretch.

If you want to design a monk npc who has a specific fighting style based around tossing traps places.  And he has a magical bag or something to store all these specially designed preloaded throwable traps in, then as the GM, that's your purview.  How strong these traps should be and how mobile he is and how many of the traps he can toss per round sound like 'balancing the encounter' question that requires a writeup of who is in the party and what tactics the party generally uses.

Maybe you have players who call bullshit unless it's pure RAW from a equal CR monster in the bestiary, but in that scenario, that's a 'players vs GM' problem not really a monk related problem and would require it's own question.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your bear trap idea is that Throw Anything gives you a bonus for your Monk to physically clock someone across the face with a thrown bear trap, not skillfully throw the bear trap on the ground and have it "magically" set itself. While such fantastic feats of dexterity aren't out of place in D&D, there aren't any explicit rules for it (that I know of).

Since you are a DM, though, it's fine for you to come up with an NPC opponent that has completely homebrew abilities. If you go this route, you should try playtesting your new opponent by coming up with a quick standard party of characters to fight him (in fact, I recommend having a mock party that represents an "average" party on hand for this kind of testing all the time, and just pulling them out whenever needed). Beware that skulking and roguish tactics can be extremely effective against PCs, to the point where [this CR 3 Pathfinder mob](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/spring-heeled-jack) caused me and my party far, far more trouble than the [CR 6 redcap](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/redcap) at the end of the dungeon. We were level 5, and it was a vertically-oriented dungeon -- a tower, so he could use his high Jump and *passwall* abilities to his extreme advantage. However, I will say that killing that shiv-wielding little midget was extremely cathartic.

Comment: The question clearly implies he is trying to hit the opponent with the trap, not setting the trap from ranged.